# Is it normal to get a lot of heal-failed entries in a gluster mount?

Tags: glusterfs

I run:

```
gluster volume heal myvol info heal-failed
```

and I get back a whole bunch of entries.  Is this normal?  Is anyone else out there seeing this in their implementation of glusterfs?  If so, how do you go about resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

List of entries from "gluster volume heal myvol info heal-failed" can be real failure or it could just list the entries which self-heal-daemon failed to self-heal in that crawl.

Gradually the file/directory which is listed under "heal-failed" entry would be self-healed by self-heal-daemon.

It is normal to see heal-failed entries.